# how to send email in simplest way using ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
require 'net/smtp'
Net::SMTP.start('host', 25) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message "Subject: testing from ruby", 'from-abc@sol.com', ['to-abc@sol.com']
  render :text=> "email sent"
end
```

my code look like this but this is not working

Comment: That is not ruby on rails it's a ruby script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Pony gem

https://github.com/benprew/pony

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a good old [RTFG](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), the rails guides are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [A simple Ruby method to send email](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/02/a-simple-ruby-method-to-send-emai/), which I tried and it works fine.

Comment: give error- No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect. i am using same code and change only to and from mail address

Answer (score 0):

I second [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805984/752076) answer.
Of course you have to change the `opts[:server]      ||= 'localhost'` line to something that actually provides an SMTP service (smtp.yourdomain.com) *and* that accepts mails from your host without smtp-auth or similar.
You may also install an SMTP server on your localhost (Postfix/qmail/exim... whatever) to serve this purpose.

Otoh: This is indeed not the "Rails" way to send email. Please have a look how to properly setup/use ActionMailer ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805962/752076) answer)